# Reading text file - for loop gives unexpected output

Tags: python

I am learning how to read txt files and find something in them. The example below outputs the entire txt file. I am trying to get it to print out "found it" when it finds the word "thanks" in the txt file. Where am I wrong?

This is the txt file I am reading:

```
this is a
demo file
for exercises
thanks
bye
```

This is the code I have written:

```
f = open("demo.txt", "r")
print(f.readline())
print(f.readline())

for word in f:
    print(word)
    if word == "thanks":
        print("found it")
```

This is the output:

```
this is a

demo file

for exercises

thanks

bye



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your line is `thanks\n` meaning it contains newline. Change `==` into `in`.

Comment: On everyline there is a special character at the end of the line for new line (\n).
So you can use ` if "thanks" in word: ` or strip the word using `word.strip() ` to remove trailing space and new line character.

Comment: Thank you @syedjafer, this is the only solution that worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("demo.txt", "r") as f:
    for word in f:
        print(word)
        if "thanks" in word:
            print("found it")
            break
```

Comment: `file.readlines()` loads the whole file in memory, which is a potential issue if file is huge, and is not necessary anyway, files are iterable so the preferred solution is, plain simply, `for line in f:` (nb also notice that those are lines, not "words")

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you are right about huge files but I think he is testing on small files considering his example. However I changed it to what you said. Also I used word because I worked on his example so I used same variable name.

Comment: the fact the OP is testing on a small file doesn't mean he shouldn't learn to do things the proper way. 20 years ago no one in his own mind would ever consider reading a whole file in memorry at once, and while we now have huge ram space, available meory can still be an issue and break a production server (think about what happens when you have hundreds of processes running parallel, each acting as if it was alone on the server).

Answer (score 0):

Files are iterable, so if you want to read a text file line by line, all you have to do is iterate over it. Also, you **must** ensure the file is closed after use - which is easily done using the `with` statement. And, finally, lines ends with the (system-dependant) newline marker, which you may want to strip for comparisons.

IOW, your code should look something like:

```
# nb: "r" (read) is the default
with open("path/to/your/file") as f:
    for line in f:
        # removes the ending newline marker 
        line = line.rstrip("\n") 
        print(line)
        # given your spec 'when it finds the word "thanks"'
        # I assume that it doesn't matter if there's
        # something else in the line, so we test for
        # containment.
        if "thanks" in line:
            print("found it")
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: @nephele you're welcome - but the way to thank someone for a useful answer is to upvote the answer (and eventually accept the one you deem as best) ;-)